# iOS: CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS, any guesses why?

Tags: ios, string, attributes, exc-bad-access

I created a method to generate an attributed string from a normal string. The `attrString` value below is non-null and correct in its content.

Upon running my application, the second line fails with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. Any idea why?

The `__bridge_retained` call is an iOS 5 requirement afaik. I've also tried `__bridge` but that has no effect, the issue still occurs.

```
    NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = (NSMutableAttributedString*)[textLayer attributedString];
    CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge_retained CFMutableAttributedStringRef)attrString);
```

**UPDATE**

If I do:

```
    NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = (NSMutableAttributedString*)[textLayer attributedString];
    NSLog(@"%@", attrString);
    CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFMutableAttributedStringRef)attrString);
```

Then the `NSLog` line won't compile; Xcode gives a warning *and* error stating `"Incompatible pointer types passing 'char[3]' to parameter of type 'NSString *'"`.

So I tried this instead:

```
    NSLog([attrString description]);
```

And this gives the following output *(I've replaced the string contents with `<snipped>` for privacy)*:

`2012-01-19 06:49:11.307 WritePath[2475:707] <Snipped>
{
    CTForegroundColor = "<CGColor 0x281530> [<CGColorSpace 0x22d1a0> (kCGColorSpaceDeviceRGB)] ( 0 0 0 1 )";
    NSFont = "<CGFont (0x28f850): ArialMT>";
    NSParagraphStyle = "CTParagraphStyle:\nwriting direction = -1, alignment = 3, line break mode = 0, default tab interval = 0\nfirst line head indent = 0, head indent = 0, tail indent = 0\nline height multiple = 0, maximum line height = 0, minimum line height = 0\nline spacing adjustment = 0, paragraph spacing = 0, paragraph spacing before = 0\ntabs:\n<CFArray 0x287b50 [0x3f229630]>{type = immutable, count = 12, values = (\n\t0 : CTTextTab: location = 28, alignment = 0, options = (none)\n\n\t1 : CTTextTab: location = 56, alignment = 0, options = (none)\n\n\t2 : CTTextTab: location = 84, alignment = 0, options = (none)\n\n\t3 : CTTextTab: location = 112, alignment = 0, options = (none)\n\n\t4 : CTTextTab: location = 140, alignment = 0, options = (none)\n\n\t5 : CTTextTab: location = 168, alignment = 0, options = (none)\n\n\t6 : CTTextTab: location = 196, alignment = 0, options = (none)\n\n\t7 : CTTextTab: location = 224, alignment = 0, options = (none)\n\n\t8 : CTTextTab: location = 252, alignment = 0, options = (none)\n\n\t9 : CTTextTab: location = 280, alignment = 0, options = (none)\n\n\t10 : CTTextTab: location = 308, alignment = 0, options = (none)\n\n\t11 : CTTextTab: location = 336, alignment = 0, options = (none)\n\n)}";
}`

Comment: You should use `__bridge` here to avoid a memory leak.  What is the output if you `NSLog("%@", attrString)`?  Paste the output into your question.

Comment: @rob Thanks for responding - I've done as you requested, see above.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said `NSLog(@"%@", attrString)`.  But what you did is ok.

Comment: Have you tried using a simpler attributed string?  E.g. `NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"hello"]`?  Or the Core Foundation version: `CFAttributedStringRef attrString = CFAttributedStringCreate(NULL, CFSTR("hello"), NULL)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I noticed this in your attributed string dump:

```
NSFont = "<CGFont (0x28f850): ArialMT>"
```

Did you create the attributed string using a `CGFontRef` as the value for the `kCTFontAttributeName` key?  You must use a `CTFontRef`, not a `CGFontRef`.  They are different.

Comment: I'm at work now but will check when I'm home in ~8 hours and respond again. Thanks a lot for the suggestion and well done for spotting that, I bet you're right :-) I'm aware they're different but I have an automatic 'attributeString' method in a CATextLayer subclass I've defined which assumes a CTFont in the 'font' property and I bet I've inadvertently set a CGFont in the constructor (both are acceptable for that property).

Comment: You were right Rob, the method works perfectly now :-) Thank you so much for taking the time to respond, it would have taken me much longer to notice my mistake. Thumbs up!

Comment: Had this exact problem and found I had put both UIFont and UIColor objects in. So thanks as this solved it.